# No module serial error when using 2 serial ports at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port

I have connected 2 serial devices to my linux (raspbian) based system. Both of them work well when the code for both devices is run separately in two different windows. But when both are made to run in the same program, I get this No module serial error. How can I correct this ?

```
serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSBport1", baudrate=2400)

serialport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSBport3',9600, timeout=1)
```

Comment: "No module serial" is not an error that Python would generate. What is the *exact* exception and traceback?

Comment: Add the error to your question - is it an import error?

Comment: @mhawke no, its not an import error. is this line the problem, serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSBport1", baudrate=2400) should it be something like serialport2 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSBport1", baudrate=2400) instead because of a name conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at this line:

> ```
> serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSBport1", baudrate=2400)
> ```

See the name that the result is bound to? Oops.

Comment: serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSBport1", baudrate=2400) should it be something like serialport2 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSBport1", baudrate=2400) instead because of a name conflict?

Comment: It's not a conflict per se. Instead you are overwriting the name, preventing the module object from being used again.